# Filtering the messages in a queue with Windows Azure

Tags: filtering, message-queue, azure-storage-queues, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there any way I can filter the messages based on properties? I mean, that only with certain properties the Worker role takes it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I'm assuming that when you talk about filtering, you mean queue-side filtering, and not client side filtering]

As far as I know, Azure Queues don't have a messaging filtering feature. If you use ServiceBus topics and subscriptions, you can filter based on message properties. See the subscription filters section of [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh699844.aspx) for more info on that.